# HTML general layout issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

The banner is where i want it to be although the boxes which are using jquery masonry are overlapping it, what have i done wrong here?...

html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="masonry.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
      $('#container').masonry({
          columnWidth: 1,
          itemSelector: 'div'
      });
});
</script>

<div id="banner">
    <img src="images/banner.png"/>
</div>

<div id="logo">
</div>

<div id="imagetrans">
<div id="container" class="clearfix masonry">

<div class="box1"> 
    <img class="bottom" src="images/eventbox2.png"/>
    <img class="top" src="images/eventbox.png"/>
</img></div>

<div class="box2">
    <img class="bottom" src="images/forumbox2.png"/>
    <img class="top" src="images/forumbox.png"/>
</img></div>    

<div class="box1"> 
    <img class="bottom" src="images/eventbox2.png"/>
    <img class="top" src="images/eventbox.png"/>
</img></div>

<div class="box1"> 
    <img class="bottom" src="images/eventbox2.png"/>
    <img class="top" src="images/eventbox.png"/>
</img></div>

<div class="box3">
    <img class="bottom" src="images/top10box2.png"/>
    <img class="top" src="images/top10box.png"/>
</img></div>

<div class="box1"> 
    <img class="bottom" src="images/eventbox2.png"/>
    <img class="top" src="images/eventbox.png"/>
</img></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
body {
  width:900px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-image: url(images/gridbg.png);
}

#banner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0px;
}

#container > div {
  margin: 5px;
}
.box1 {
  width:350px;
  height:250px;
}

.box2 {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}

.box3 {
  width:150px;
  height:350px;
}

#imagetrans {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#imagetrans img.top:hover,
#container > div img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

#imagetrans img,
#container > div img {
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Any ideas? cause i can easily place the banner at the bottom by changing the coding from top to bottom, although i would prefer it if i could have it at the top of the screen, not quite sure whats wrong...

[image]

Comment: where in the html file do you include your css file?

Comment: in the head yet just havent included that, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
#banner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0px;
}
```

To:

```
#banner {
   height: 100px; // whatever your banner height is.
}
```

Or:

```
#banner {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0px;
}
```

If you do the position fixed approach, you'll need to add a top margin or spacer of some sort to bump the page contents down by the height of your header.

Comment: height: 100px works although this then stops the image being repeated  horizontally and the second one does the same thing as current code... any other ideas?

Comment: Which image doesn't get repeated horizontally? You could also just add  a style for #logo { margin-top: 100px; } (or whatever the height of your header is). Basically the #banner { position: absolute; } is making the header not take up space in the layout so the rest of the contents don't get pushed down.

Comment: yea adding a style for logo like you suggessted has filled the gap, probably not the best way around it but its worked so thats good enough for me aha! thanks.